I want to print a label in a thermal labels printer using a React Application
My colleague and I have been wondering if there is any npm package or something similar that can help us to print a personalized thermal label. We would like to use this printer if thats ok: VRETTI 4 x 6Thermal Shipping Label Printer 420B USB
We saw that there is a npm package for the EPSON printers but we would like to try with this one. Does it works wit the Vretti?
We have already developed an app to print in a MUNBYN for thermal tickets, but now, the challenge is to print labels which is more complicated as we have to design a way to fit the whole info inside the label, so I guess there are more parameters needed, am I right?
We are using a React Application with javascript, HTML, CSS, MongoDB...
This is the code we used for the thermal tickets printer:
import Printer from "escpos";
import Network from "escpos-network";
import TicketCounter from "../../models/Counter/TicketCounter.model.js";

export const printTicketCounter = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id, weights } = req.body;
    const ticketToEdit = await TicketCounter.findById(id);

     if (!ticketToEdit) {
       return res.status(404).json({ message: "Ticket not found" });
     }

     // Filter out the weight with the specified weightId
     ticketToEdit.weights = weights;

     // Save the updated ticket
     const updatedTicket = await ticketToEdit.save();
    
    if (!updatedTicket) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "Ticket not found" });
    }

    const device = new Network("192.168.1.45"); // Create a new instance for each print job
    const printer = new Printer(device);

    device.open(function (error) {
      if (error) {
        console.error("Error al abrir la impresora:", error);
        return res
          .status(500)
          .json({
            success: false,
            message: "Error al abrir la impresora",
            error,
          });
      }

      // Print title and client name
      printer
        .font("A")
        .align("CT")
        .style("B")
        .size(0.5, 0.5)
        .text("Ticket")
        .text(`Cliente: ${updatedTicket.clientName}`)
        .text("-----------------------------")
        .align("LT");

      // Print items with shortened details

      
      updatedTicket.weights.forEach((item) => {
        printer.text(
          `${item.materialName.padEnd(12)} $${item.price.toFixed(2)}`
        );
        printer.text(
          `Peso: ${item.weight.toFixed(2)}kg Tara: ${item.tare.toFixed(2)}kg`
        );
        printer.text(`Neto: ${(item.weight - item.tare).toFixed(2)}kg`);
        printer.text(
          `Total: ${(item.price * (item.weight - item.tare)).toFixed(2)}`
        );
        printer.text("-----------------------------");
      });

      // Print total and footer
      printer
        .align("CT")
        .text(`Total: $${updatedTicket.total.toFixed(2)}`)
        .text("Gracias por su preferencia")
        .text("-----------------------------")
        .cut()
        .close(() => {
          console.log("Print job completed and connection closed");
         
         
          
         
          res
            .status(200)
            .json({ success: true, data: "Ticket printed successfully" });
        });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error en printTicketCounter:", error);
    res
      .status(500)
      .json({ success: false, message: "Error al imprimir", error });
  }
};


Is there any way we can use this same library for the label printer? Any other npm package... By the way, this last code is for a MUNBYN WIFI printer, we are coneecting via wifi, we dont care if the label printer can be connected to the app via usb or bluetooth...

Is Vretti made by Epson ? Or is Epson made by Vretti? why would you think they are compatible?

Hey! I don't know! I was just wondering if they probably use the same escape commands... do you know that?

So have you tried sending the escape commands? Surely a simple thing you can test...
